# Archives for Blog

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating an archives navigation on my website and have found a few posts regarding how to do it and have pulled together some code, but can't seem to get it to work.

I want it to display like:

```
January 2015 (9) 
December 2014 (8) 
November 2014 (10) 
October 2014 (15)
...
```

Here's the code :

```
$sql = "SELECT YEAR(timestamp_published) AS 'year', Month(timestamp_published) AS 'month', COUNT(id) AS 'count' FROM table GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp_published), MONTH(timestamp_published) DESC";
$data = $db->query($sql);

while($row = $db->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[$row['year']][$row['month']] = $row['count'];
}

foreach ($data as $year => $months) {
 echo archive_date($month).' ';
   foreach ($months as $month => $count) {
     echo $year.' ('.$count.') (' . $data->id . ')<br/>';
}
   }
}
```

Thank you! I ended up solving my own issue. I was building this in a class and there were a couple of issues. I've got the code working now, here it is for anyone in the future.

```
$sql = "SELECT YEAR(timestamp_published) AS 'year', MONTH(timestamp_published) AS 'month', COUNT(`publish`) AS 'count' FROM ".static::$table_name." GROUP BY YEAR(timestamp_published) DESC, MONTH(timestamp_published) ASC";
$result = $db->query($sql);
$data = array();
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $data[$row['year']][$row['month']] = $row['count'];
}

foreach ($data as $year => $months) {
  echo '<strong>'.$year.'</strong><br/><br/>';
foreach ($months as $month => $count) {
  $dateObj = DateTime::createFromFormat('!m', $month);
  $monthName = $dateObj->format('F'); // March
  echo $monthName . ' ('.$count.')<br/>';
}
  echo '<hr/>';
}
```

It actually comes out looking like this:

2015 
 January (3) 
 February (5) 
 March (6) 
 ... 

2014 
 January (7) 
 February (9) 
 ...

Comment: What is the output of the code you have provided? Any errors?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are looking to get the string representation of the month (bit unclear) but that can be achieved by using `date()` like so

```
date ("F", $month)
```

so in your case

```
echo date ("F", $month) . ' ' . $year.' ('.$count.')<br/>';
```